# SharePoint 2013 Workflow - Update List Item Based on Two Columns

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, updatelistitems

I'm not sure if this is possible.  I would like to have a SharePoint 2013 workflow update a list item in another list only if: column A contains 'x' and column B contains 'y'.

I know I am able to compare a single column but I need two as there will be multiple values that match in the first column.

Example of what I want in SharePoint.

```
If ( val1 == x && val2 == y ){ 
    update (This) item.
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright ladies and gentlemen here's the answer:

I was able to use an HTTP call to get and loop through the items on the 2nd list.  Then I was able to check the values of each column on each item and find the specific item I needed.  Knowing that allowed me to update that specific item and that item only with the new data from List A.

For more information on how to setup and use the HTTP call check [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013).

Thanks for the all help / suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Happily, this is straightforward to achieve.

What you need to do is insert a section 'If' action immediately after the first, ensuring the 'and/or' toggle is set correctly at the second (and subsequent) 'If' statements.

You should end up with something that looks like the following screenshot

[image: SPD2013 Multiple If Statements]

Where the Column A value is in a separate list you will need to lookup that value as shown in the attached screenshot

[image]

which essentially translates to : GET 'Column A' FROM 'List B' WHERE 'List B lookup field' EQUALS 'lookup value'.

The end result will look and work the same as before, albeit with the value of Column A being retrieved from List B rather than the current list.

Comment: This should work for updating an item in the same list as the workflow.  My issue is that I need the workflow to check two columns in a 2nd list.

 More like if Column A (in list B) equals x and Column B (in list B) equals y...etc

Comment: In that case you would need to 'look up' the Column A value in the other list.  I have updated by answer

Comment: Ok I've run into an issue with this method.  While it seems to work ok for detecting if those values exist together in List B, How do you tell the "Update List Item" which entry to update?  There is still only a single Field selection for that action.  Its almost like we need a "This" now that we've had the nested IF find the correct entry.  -- I've update my post to reflect this need --

Comment: It's starting to get a little tricky to give a constructive answer without a better understanding of the use case and the processes/data involved.  I've a couple of further suggestions:  Can you not associate the workflow with the 'Other' list as that seems to be where most of the 'work' is happening?

Comment: If this is not possible, then I feel you will need to create a specific 'lookup' field in the target list - concatenating the Col A & B values, then perform the lookup against that.  Failing that I think you'll need to look at a coded solution

Comment: Thanks for the help Fairfield.  I'll look into concatenating into a single value as I believe that will be the easiest.  I've looked into using an HTTP call to gather all the data from List B and then using a loop to go through it and check the two columns, but I receive errors.