# Document Library Workflow fill a custom field in a "assign task"

Tags: 2013, workflow

How to set a value for custom field in **Workflow Tasks** list item.

When task is assign to user, I'm trying to set value for custom field (**priority**).

Value contains inforamion about related item from document library.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: You need to update the column value? With workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below links for the update the custom column/field.

[Reference Link1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59266/how-do-i-have-a-workflow-update-set-a-field-in-the-current-list#answers-header)
[Reference Link2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173782/sharepoint-2013-workflow-update-list-item-based-on-two-columns#answers-header)

Reference Link for [Video](https://www.visualsp.com/module-1/sp10creating-a-workflow-on-a-list-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/) to do it.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To set value for custom column in task list for current task item.

[image]

1. TaskID of Assign Task action is equal to GUID of task list item.Both have same value
2. So use above column for lookup to set value
3. In Image you can see my task list name is Active Directory Correction request task
4. I'm set value for Priority column in task list for current task
5. At the bottom I have used lookup condition where GUID filed value from Task list is equal to TaskID value

Comment: Dear, My wf waiting completion on the task to do next step, I need to reflect it once create

Comment: It means you have not taken any action(Approve/Reject) on Workflow

Comment: where did you use that update action for task list column. It will be great if you share screen shots of your workflow